# Finding in an intersection of a rectangle in a iterating list

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

I'm having an issue when trying to find an intersection of a rectangle. I have a list of rectangles that are being drawn to the screen in a for loop. I want to find if the mouse intersects with any of them, but I think the problem is that iteration happens so fast that it's impossible to detect a collision. Is there any better way of finding intersections in a list of rectangles?

The code I've tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < drawTangle.Count; i++)
{
    mouse.Update(gameTime);
    if (mouse.clickRectangle.Intersects(drawTangle[x]) && mouse.LeftClicked())
    {
        info = listOfInfo[x];
        isDrawingList = false;
        moreInfo = true;
    }
}
```

AND

```
mouse.Update(gameTime);
if (mouse.clickRectangle.Intersects(drawTangle[x]) && mouse.LeftClicked())
{
    info = listOfInfo[x];
    isDrawingList = false;
    moreInfo = true;
}
x += 1;
if (x == drawTangle.Count)
   x = 0;
```

But neither of these will detect the intersections (well at least for us slow humans).

Any suggestions?

Variables:

```
    Dictionary<string, Information> infoList;
    List<string> listOfInfo;
    List<Rectangle> drawTangle;
```

Drawing code:

```
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(window, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        if (isDrawingList)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < drawTangle.Count; i++)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(button, drawTangle[i], Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, infoList[listOfInfo[i]].name, new Vector2(drawTangle[i].X + 8, drawTangle[i].Y + 4), Color.Black);
            }

        }
        else if (moreInfo)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, infoList[info].name, new Vector2((GraphicsDeviceManager.DefaultBackBufferWidth / 2) - infoList[listOfInfo].name.Length / 2, 4), Color.Black);
        }
    }
```

Mouse methods:

```
    public bool LeftClicked()
    {
        if (currentmouse.LeftButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Pressed
            && oldmouse.LeftButton == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Released)
        {
            clickedonce = true;
            time = gametime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds + .5f;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

AND

```
clickRectangle = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, 3, 3);
```

Comment: Try and read the code you provided us as a person that doesn't have your full code, and doesn't know what you've done so far. Can you see how unclear it is?

Comment: @YoryeNathan Sorry about that. Let me update to code.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Is this more clear? Or should I add more?

Comment: What do you mean "iteration happens so fast that it's impossible to detect a collision"? Once you get a mouse click wouldn't you just go through your rectangles and check each one, if the mouse is in a rectangle then do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: it looks like your LeftClicked routine doesn't actually check for intersections/collisions?

Comment: @Paul0712 You are exactly right, I should check fir a click then compare, not check for an intersection and click. I have fixed my problem thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul0712 mentioned I should check for a click then check for intersections.

Updated code:

```
    public void Update(MouseInput mouse)
    {
            if (mouse.LeftClicked())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < drawTangle.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (mouse.clickRectangle.Intersects(drawTangle[i]))
                    {
                        diseaseToInfo = listOfInfo[i];
                        isDrawingList = false;
                        moreInfo = true;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```